# Helmfile annotations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have one question regarding helmfile. The question is: how to set annotations to deployment using helmfile? I've tried by using set instruction but It's not working. Also didn't find any information in docs.

Comment: Is there a particular chart you're trying to install using Helmfile?  It's hard to directly inject content into the generated YAML files; it mostly depends on being able to provide appropriate values to the chart you're installing, and the chart knowing how to produce the annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked very similar stack question [How do I assign value to variable in helmfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856305/how-do-i-assign-value-to-variable-in-helmfile)?

you can do [like this](https://github.com/cloudposse/geodesic/blob/0.12.0/rootfs/conf/kops/helmfile.yaml#L63-L137)

```
set:
- name: "ingress.annotations.kubernetes\\.io/ingress\\.class"
  value: "nginx"
  ...
```

or [like that](https://github.com/cloudposse/helmfiles/blob/0.2.4/helmfile.d/0300.chartmuseum.yaml#L65-L83)

```
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set annotation from helm cli, you can make it like this example:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.annotations."cloud\.google\.com\/load-balancer\-type"=Internal
```